# Creating a standalone Python application using cx_Freeze in macOS

Tags: python, macos

I want to convert a Python 3.5 script to a standalone application that can be executable on macOS using cx_Freeze.

I have created the setup.py file, but when I execute the setup script:

```
python3.5 setup.py dbist_mac
```

This error comes up:

```
 copying libicudata.54.1.dylib -> build/exe.macosx-10.6-x86_64 3.5/libicudata.54.1.dylib
 error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'libicudata.54.1.dylib'
```

I'm currently working with PyQt5. Thanks in advance!